# CDKTF C# how to include providers that do not have a pre-built provider - namespace confusion

Tags: c#, terraform, namespaces, csproj, terraform-cdk

I am new to C# and I've been able to build out an application for a client using the pre-built providers for CDKTF and Azure. My question is when there is **not** a pre-built provider, how do I include the bindings in my code? I see that with typescript it's as simple as `import { YourProvider } from './gen/providers/<yourprovider>/provider';` (referenced from [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/providers#import-classes)).

The problem is that in C#, it's not so straightforward it seems. I have been searching for the answer but haven't found anything yet. I think that it might be such a basic question that it's difficult to find someone asking the question, or I don't know the proper terminology to be able to find it. I also tried ChatGPT but it's explanations weren't on point (implying the issue is my lack of understanding/proper vocabulary)

I see that the provider exists at `.gen/azuredevops/azuredevops/Provider/AzuredevopsProvider.cs` and it has a namespace of `azuredevops.Provider` but when I try to do

```
using azuredevops.Provider
```

it can't find it. Does this have something to do with the .csproj file?

Any help in understanding how to include this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to your `.csproj` file, e.g.:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include=".gen\azuredevops\azuredevops.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

See [this example](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/blob/main/examples/csharp/azure/MyTerraformStack.csproj#L13) for reference.

Comment: I've added this but I'm not sure now what i would do to import it. I see in the code here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/blob/main/examples/csharp/azure/Main.cs#L3 the person writes using azurerm.Provider;    but when I try to do using azuredevops.Provider; it throws an error saying The type or namespace name 'azuredevops' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate it.

Comment: i realized the issue after you showed me this. I didn't realize that I needed to run `dotnet build` as well after adding the reference. Since i already had code referencing it, it was not buildable so i thought it wasn't importing it. I just had to remove all references to the package, and then run `dotnet build` and it worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: also, FWIW, if you strongly dislike using a GUI to build configuration, the command to add the package is `dotnet add <Main .csproj file> reference <path to new .csproj file>`. 

The answer does not use a GUI, but most of my searching found people telling me to click on stuff in visual studio, which I don't use, so figured I'd share this as well